# What class should I inherit to create a database integration test in case of Spring?

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring, integration-testing

I want to create a unit test for integration testing. What class should I inherit to be able to commit/rollback transactions? `AbstractTransactionalSpringContextTests` is deprecated. It's recommended to use `AbstractJUnit38SpringContextTests` instead, but I cannot find how to control transactions there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Check this](http://bozhobg.wordpress.com/2009/11/22/database-integration-testing-with-spring-jpa-junit-and-maven/) and [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/testing.html#testcontext-framework)

In short, you need:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations="classpath:/applicationContext.xml")
public class YourTest {

    @Transactional
    public void someTest() {
    }
}
```

That would mean you need JUnit 4.x

Answer (score 0):

No need to put the `@Transactional` in the method level you can directly place it in class level

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations="classpath:applicationContext.xml")
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=true, transactionManager="transactionManager")
@Transactional
public class YourTest {

    @Rollback(true)
    public void someTest() {
    }

}
```